# Nonblocking MPI and rendezvous protocol

Tags: mpi, deadlock

I don't completely understand how MPI's nonblocking communication and rendezvous protocol are supposed to interact.

Firstly, consider this pseudocode, which can block when rendezvous protocol is used (assume we are having 2 processes):

```
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Send (big_message, destination=1)
    MPI_Recv(source=1)
} else {
    MPI_Send(big_message, destination=0)
    MPI_Recv(source=0)
}
```

This can obviously block when message is too big to fit in the internal buffer, as `MPI_Send`s in both processes would wait for a matching receive to be posted.

On my system, I have found the following modification to work:

```
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Isend (big_message, destination=1, &request)
    MPI_Recv(source=1)
    MPI_Wait(request)
} else {
    MPI_Isend(big_message, destination=0, &request)
    MPI_Recv(source=0)
    MPI_Wait(request)
}
```

We use nonblocking communication for sending the message. Would my solution be correct on every implementation of MPI? I have read that the implementations are not mandated to initiate any form of communication when `MPI_Isend` is called, and can perform it upon calling `MPI_Wait`. Would such implementation break my code? My understanding is that in such cicumstances `MPI_Isend` is basically a no-op and, for my code, both processes would wait in `MPI_Recv` for a send which does not come.

If my pseudocode is non-portable is there a way of using nonblocking communication to fix it?

Comment: Your solution is correct, and an even better solution is to use `MPI_Sendrecv()`. Under the hood, (enough) communications (e.g. sending the message) are guaranteed to progressed during `MPI_Recv()`, that is why the second version will never hang.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that all communication can happen at the wait call is a simplistic view, and probably only correct if all communication is non-blocking. Taken strictly it would mean that your code would deadlock on the blocking receives because the sends would happen after them. That does not happen.

For your case, section 3.7.4 of the standard say that that "[...] a call to `MPI_Wait` that completes a send will eventually return if a matching receive has been started [... some notes...]" So, yes, your code is correct.